# How to handle in-app purchase scenario?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Lets say I have website where user can purchase subsciption x,y,z and I have app where user can also buy same subsciption. What happen when user alredy bought sub on website and then login to app? Can we push informations to apple server or just check in app with our backend if user has sub and ignore apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the multiple plateform scenario you have to maintain the server DB along with the status of the account is either purchased or not. If user is paid then which type of subscription (x,y,z) it is. For app (android, iOS), you have to use API's and for web  you have fetch data from server DB.

> Can we push informations to apple server.

No, you can not do this. Apple IAP data only maintains that you have purchased from the IAP. And same as for the google in app purchase.

Hope now you have been cleared.